# SSIS can't connect to DB2 running in SQL Server: ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, odbc

I have an SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2019 using an ADO.NET connection manager with provider **.Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider**. When running on my development machine, everything works fine.

However, after deploying the package to the target SQL Server, this error occurs:

> Data Flow Task: Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection
> with the following error message: "ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed".

- The driver being used is **IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER, version 11.01.00.1527**.
- The correct SQL version is targeted
- The package is running in 32 bit mode
- The username and password to the database are passed into the package via project parameters
- The default connection string is Dsn=*Dsn-name*;uid=*Username*

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue.

Comment: Is the 32bit IBM ODBC driver installed?  Have you rebooted since installing it?

Comment: Have you read through the [DB2 ODBC CLI driver Download and Installation information](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-odbc-cli-driver-download-and-installation-information) notes yet? Could be a similar 32/64 bit issue as mentioned in the _Data source name not found and no default driver specified_ section.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I have asked our server support person to verify this, however I used the same install on my dev machine and 32-bit is installed. I do not believe the server was rebooted since the install.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I have forwarded that post to our server support person. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I was logged into the SQL server via SSMS and running the SSIS package, we had to add my user ID to the group DB2ADMNS on the SQL server. I did see numerous posts across the web suggesting this.